# SQLite date function failing on datetime which includes UTC designator ("Z")

Tags: php, sqlite

> select date('1994-11-05T13:15:30Z');

The above query is returning null...

The date appears to be valid as far as I can tell (tried this query in MySQL and it worked ok).

I'm using PHP 5.4.14

Comment: I have MySql and I ran this query and it returned '11/5/1994 12:00:00 AM' On sqlfiddle.com using the SQLlite function it returns '1994-11-05'
With this is mind, are you accessing the results properly in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not necessarily use the same SQL as MySQL does. Very few SQL dialects are completely compatible with ANSI SQL, so one cannot expect SQL from one database system to work in another system.

According to the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), `date` should work similarly to the one in MySQL. However the timezone modifier of ISO 8601 does not seem to be supported at all. If you need the timezone (which I am not sure of if you only need the date), you could try the following (that I cannot test right now):

```
SELECT date('1994-11-05T13:15:30', 'utc')
```